# "Show All Files" option missing in VS Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, database-project

The VS Database Project does not seem to have the "Show All Files" option in the Solution Explorer.  Does anyone know of a way to turn the option on in VS?

The "Show All Files" option on the solution explorer actually does two things.  With the option selected, VS shows "hidden/nested" files within the project AND it shows files within the directory of the project that are not currently part of the project.  (It shows the latter with a ghosted icon.)

While DB projects may not have nested or hidden files within the project, there is no other way that I know of  to have the solution explorer show files within the directory that are not part of the project.

Also, while this action occurs within the solution explorer, it is actually a project issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer to this issue is:-

You must have the Database Project root node selected in the Solution Explorer.

Selecting any other node in the Solution Explorer other than the Database Project root node will cause the "Show All Files" button to become hidden.

Answer (score -1):

it is by design. Some project types just don't allow you to. You might be able to go into the sln file in notepad and try something, but it might just screw up your solution.